# how does the java operator work?

Tags: java, database, database-schema

so im trying to implement the addition operator in my simpleDB database. ive got most of it done but i have no idea how to add the 2 parts. so this would be used in a query for the database , and i want to be able to add the left hand side and right hand side. what java methods can use to do that? since in the simpleDB there is no addition operator.

this was how i implemented the < operator

```
 if (operator.equals("<") && lhsval.compareTo(rhsval) < 0) {
         return true;
      }
```

like right now i have

```
 Constant lhsval = lhs.evaluate(s);
      Constant rhsval = rhs.evaluate(s);
    if (operator.equals("+")) {
             // return ;
           }
```

i have the left hand side and the right side
so when the query sees the + sign , its goin to add em togther and return the answer. but i have no idea how. when i implemented the less than operator, i used the comprateTo method and when i did the equal operator i used the equals method. i have no idea what i can use for the addition operator.btw this is using java

constant class

```
package simpledb.query;

/**
 * The interface that denotes values stored in the database.
 * @author Edward Sciore
 */
public interface Constant extends Comparable<Constant> {

   /**
    * Returns the Java object corresponding to this constant.
    * @return the Java value of the constant
    */
   public Object  asJavaVal();
}
```

Comment: Not quite clear, are you trying to concatenate various components of a query that would be sent to a database to fetch records?

Comment: have you try `lhsval.concat(rhsval)`

Comment: cant use concat either, its not implemented. thats what makes this hard lol

Comment: You can always use `lhsval.asJavaVal()` to get an `Integer`. These can be added normally and be returned as `new IntConstant`.

Comment: what is `Constant`?? somme classe you created??

Comment: yeah its a constant that the simpleDB code already has implemented. i updated it above with what it is

Answer (score 1):

A relational operator such as A lower than B has been implemented because the type Constant implements Comparable.

If you want to implement a relational operator such as A + B then the type Constant has to implement a type such as Addable? I think yes, it has to.

```
    Constant lhsval = lhs.evaluate(s);
    Constant rhsval = rhs.evaluate(s);
    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        return lhsval.add(rhsval);
    }
```

The Addable interface has this contract:

```
    interface Addable extends RelationalOperator {
        Constant add(Constant lhs, Constant rhs);    
    }
```

You have to decide how the add operator has to work (concatenate, sum, depends on Constant subtype, ...)

**Edited after update on question**

A simple implementation is to use the method `Object  asJavaVal();` as follow:

```
    Constant lhsval = lhs.evaluate(s);
    Constant rhsval = rhs.evaluate(s);
    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        Object lhsObj = lhs.asJavaVal();
        Object rhsObj = lhs.asJavaVal();  
        // here check for null and same type of lhs, rhs
        ...
        // now use typed implementation of + 
        if (lhsObj instanceof BigDecimal)
           return new ConstantImpl(lhsval.add(rhsval));
        else if (lhsObj instanceof String)
           return new ConstantImpl(lhsval + rhsval);
        else if (lhsObj instanceof ...) 
           return new ConstantImpl(...);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid type for + :"+ lhsObj.getClass());
    }
```

Comment: yeah , this stuff i kinda hard to follow unless i link u to the site that has the simpleDB package so u can run it on eclipse and see all the code. but i doubt anyone would want to do that lol. thanks for help . ill see if what u said helps me

Comment: @henryzo I don't promise that I can see all the code but if you want to link the full implementation of simpleDB I'll look at it.

Comment: http://csns.calstatela.edu/wiki/content/cysun/course_materials/cs422/simpledb   you should be looking at teh parse code and term code

Comment: @henryzo I've looked at the source code and I've read the paper http://www.cs.bc.edu/~sciore/papers/SIGCSE07.pdf. It's not so simple to aswer your question. As first thing I think you should change the title of the question because there's a strong specificity about SimpleDB.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is better to check the type of **lhsval** and **rhsval**. After that you can get values of known type by **asJavaVal**:

```
Constant lhsval = lhs.evaluate(s);
Constant rhsval = rhs.evaluate(s);
Constant res = null;
if (operator.equals("+")) {
    if (lhsval instanceof IntConstant) {
        int sum = (Integer) lhsval.asJavaVal() + (Integer) rhsval.asJavaVal();
        res = new IntConstant(sum);
    } else if (lhsval instanceof StringConstant) {
        String sum = ((String) lhsval.asJavaVal()).concat((String) rhsval.asJavaVal());
        res = new StringConstant(sum);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown constant type");
    }
}
```